# How to wait for an alert to pop up before proceeding without making it necessary for the user to tap to proceed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm a beginner to Flutter, and in my current (first) project I have an alert that I want to pop up before the next bit of code runs.

If I use `await` I have found that it then requires the user to tap on the screen (outside the bounds of the alert) in order for the program to continue. Is there any way to just make sure the alert is present before proceeding without requiring the tap?

Here is my alert method:

```
myAlert(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Some text'),
        );
      },
    );
}
```

I call the method and then in the next line call another method which does some intensive computations:

```
myAlert(context);
compute();
```

Both methods are called on the press of a button (I don't know if this would be relevant in any way, so just putting it out there).

I want `compute()` to be called only after the alert appears. As of right now, `compute()` begins running before the alert pops up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit confusing, but if you want compute to run when creating the dialog, run it inside the builder (a better option might be to create a separate widget and do it in his initState).

```
myAlert(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new MyAlertDialog();
      },
    );
}
```

> my_alert_dialog.dart

```
class MyAlertDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAlertDialogState createState() => _MyAlertDialogState();
}

class _MyAlertDialogState extends State<MyAlertDialog> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    compute()//HERE u can du your compute
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return //Build here your Dialog Content...
  }
}
```

If you wanna wait for the dialog  close and then execute your compute, use await.

```
myAlert(BuildContext context) async{
    return await showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Some text'),
        );
      },
    );
}
```

Comment: For some reason this works when I click the button for the first time, yet after that if I click the button again it reverts to first running `compute()` and only after showing the alert. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: are you awaiting? or using compute on initState in your dialog?

Comment: I just put compute in the builder for now to test it out.